# Vacation day formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need help with a complex multi-evaluation furmula for computing vacation days. It is in a workbook that can not be macro-enabled so must be in formula form. I need it to do the following evaluations:

How long has the employee been working: Under a year = 0 hours, 1-3 years = 40 Hours, 3+ years 80 hours

Then on a weekly pay chart based on todays date in comparison with the current weeks dates show 
column 1 - how many hours the employee has accrued
Column 2 - how many taken this week
Column 3 - How many hours remain

And the kicker is when I open excel I don't want it to reevalutes any of the previous weeks numbers.

Here is the current code I have. J3 is hire date, A9 start of week, C9 end of Week, E8 Starting vacation balance. I8 is used hours, M8 is final balance.

```
=IF(TODAY()<C9,E9,IF(AND(DATE(,MONTH($A9),DAY($A9))<=DATE(,MONTH($J$3),DAY($J$3)),DATE(,MONTH($C9),DAY($C9))>=DATE(,MONTH($J$3),DAY($J$3))),IF(TODAY()>DATE(YEAR($J$3)+3,MONTH($J$3),DAY($J$3)),80,IF(TODAY()>DATE(YEAR($J$3)+1,MONTH($J$3),DAY($J$3)),40,0)),E8))
```

Is it possible to do all I need without macro-enabled

Comment: show a visual example of records and output. Also explain your 'kicker' more.

Comment: To answer your question: Yes, it is possible.  If you require assistance I suggest providing examples of your data input, desired output, and the problem with your formulaic approach. The help topic [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) may be useful.

Comment: Is there a way to attach the workbook or does it have to be a external link? The kicker is: most of the formulas use the Today() function so everytime the workbooks opens it recaculates the data. What I need is for it to not erase previous accruals & balances and over right them but only do the current week.

Comment: @Hareborn External link.  And, without VBA, you will not be able to keep the `TODAY()` function from recalculating unless you manually replace the function with the date.  Sorry about that, I missed thinking about the implications of that function when I first responded.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8-D2kOqUJJwTUJ5UkZpbUJFM2s

Comment: @Hareborn I see this is in Google Sheets.  I'm not familiar with the fine points of that program.  In Excel, you can create a "static" date/time based on the `TODAY` function by using a circular reference and allowing iteration.  This would be way of accomplishing the action without VBA.  But I have no idea about Google sheets.

Comment: If you download it, it is a excel workbook, google drive auto converts to googlesheet if you just view it.

Comment: @Hareborn How do the vacation hours accrue?  Is it proportional to the fraction of a year worked since hired date?  Or do they accrue at the end of 1 year of work?  Or on some particular day in the year (eg. 31 Dec)?

Comment: It's a lump sum given at the end of the years worked on the anniversy date, so first year is zero, 2 & 3 years is 40 hours and 3+ is 80 Hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any reason you need the `TODAY` function to calculate accrued vacation time.  If I understand you correctly, at the

- end of year 1:  Accrued = 0 hrs
- end of year 2:  Accrued = 40 hrs
- end of year 3:  Accrued = 80 hrs
- end of year 4:  Accrued = 160 hrs
- end of year 5:  Accrued = 240 hrs

etc

My suggestion:

Set up a Table as below; `NAME` if `Vacation_Table`  Note the formula in `B5` in case you have to change column 1 break points, or any of the other parameters: (I put this on another worksheet, but you can put it anyplace.

[image]

Then use this formula to compute the vacation hours accrued from the `hire date` to the `start of the week date` (Change A9 to C9 if you want the hours accrued to the end of the week).

```
=VLOOKUP(DATEDIF($J$3,A9,"y"),Vacation_Table,2)+ (DATEDIF($J$3,A9,"y")-VLOOKUP(DATEDIF($J$3,A9,"y"),Vacation_Table,1))*VLOOKUP(DATEDIF($J$3,A9,"y"),Vacation_Table,3)
```

Of course, to get the current balance, you will need to subtract from this the vacation hours used, but this should give you a start with non-volatile formulas.

Comment: I got so stuck on trying to use the Today() function that I didn't see the work around, thanks for pointing me in a different direction.